# Filter all dicts in a list to be with specific keys and ignore others?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following list of dicts:

```
lst = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'd':3}, {'a':1, 'c':2, 'k':3}, {'d':1, 'k':2, 'l':3}]
```

I want to filter the list of dicts (in my case it's a list of thousands or even more dicts, with different keys with some overlap) to be a list containing all the dicts that have keys: ["a", "b"]. I want to filter each dict only to these `a` and `b` keys, and if they don't exist, don't include the dictionary in the final list. I am using:

```
[{"a": d.get("a"), "b": d.get("b")} for d in lst]
```

Please advise for an elegant way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out and here is my alternative:

```
lst = [{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}, {'a':1, 'b':2, 'd':3}, {'a':1, 'c':2, 'k':3}, {'d':1, 'k':2, 'l':3}]
keys = set("ab")
[i for i in [{k: d.get(k) for k in keys if k in d} for d in lst] if i]
```

Gives the desired answer:

```
[{'b': 2, 'a': 1}, {'b': 2, 'a': 1}, {'a': 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary keys-view is set-like, so it supports subset comparisons by using `<=` operator:

```
>>> keys = set("ab")
>>> [{k: d[k] for k in keys} for d in lst if keys <= d.keys()]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Comment: This is not what I asked for, I don't need other keys, I want each dict to be with the set of keys I want say "a" and "b" and ignore others. @wim

Comment: @SteveS OK, updated - it's hard to tell exactly what you need since the expected output wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: Why should I have the ```if keys <= d.keys()```? I have tried without it and it worked. @wim

Comment: @SteveS Well the question currently says "_...and if they don't exist, don't include the dictionary in the final list_".  Now, the third dict in your input `lst` has key "a" but is missing key "b", so it should be dropped IIUC.